# Does IOT hardware for apple review should be complient with FCC?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, appstore-approval

I've made an app that connects to BLE device (my device based on module HM-10C with FCC). My app was rejected from appstore review process with remark about hardware needed. I'm ready to send hardware but in apple response also written about FCC:

> IMPORTANT: for non-US Developers
>
> To avoid delays with US Customs, please provide the following
>   information with your shipment (required for all radio-frequency
>   devices imported in the US):

My hardware device not been authorized for FCC rules and not intended for US market.

Is it possible to send device without FCC but with remark:

> The described equipment is being imported in limited quantities for
>   testing and evaluation for compliance with technical  requirements or
>   marketing suitability.

Does anybody has experience with iOT, FCC and Apple?

**Updated:**
We have did following steps to get approved review for iOT BLE device:

1. Filled [FCC 740 form](https://transition.fcc.gov/Forms/Form740/740.pdf) with 'X' on remark 'equipment is being imported in limited quantities for testing and evaluation'. FCC ID: 'NOT REQUIRED'
2. Placed label on top of box with text: 'This device has not been authorized as required by the rules of the Federal Communications Commission. This device is not, and may not be, offered for sale or lease, or sold or leased, until authorization is obtained'
3. Box was wrapped with air-polyethylene
4. Documents ( Invoice and FCC form ) placed on top of the box
5. Sent to Apple Inc by Express DHL shipping

Review approved !

Comment: Usually it is enough to add a video which demonstrates how app is interacting with your device. Really no need to send anything to Apple. We're always recording the video (QuickTime/Reflector), uploading it to Dropbox and providing the link in submission notes.

Comment: Unfortunately video is not enough for some application. We have two app in Apple store, both apps works with hardware.
First application works thru Wireless by HTTP protocol and video was  enough to pass review.
Second applications works thru BLE and video, strub access was not enough to pass review.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your original question Dmitry. This helps us a lot here in Malaysia with the same App Store Rejection.

Comment: The issue we are now facing is that DHL is requesting us to send the FCC 740 document to Apple first for signature etc! Did you do this?

Comment: We have sent FCC 740 form together with device